# Text in Flex's list

Tags: apache-flex, list

How can locate text in the mx:List like this?

```
|"text1"         "test2"|
 -----------------------
|"text3"         "text4"|
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to look at wordWrap="false|true" or just do something like this (you can add this code to your flex application and see - it works perfectly)

```
<mx:List>   
<mx:String>"text"        "text"</mx:String>
<mx:String>"text2"        "text3"</mx:String>
<mx:String>"text4"        "text5"</mx:String>
</mx:List>
```

So all you have to do is convert your variables to strings and join 3 strings

```
         "text1" +   "               " + "text2"
```

And BTW at "Adobe® Flex™ 3 Language Reference" you can find it all=)

---

**The other way**
Is to create costume Item renderer. Good tutorial on this is on [GoToAndLearn.com](http://gotoandlearn.com/)  in Introduction to Flex: Part 2 and 3 ("...create a custom Flex component and use it as an item renderer for the List control...")

Comment: i usually go with the sexy nurse costume item renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to make a custom item renderer that has a layout like:

```
<mx:HBox width="100%">
  <mx:Label text="{data.value1}" />
  <mx:Spacer width="100%" />
  <mx:Label text="{data.value2}" />
</mx:HBox>
```

The spacer will dynamically adjust itself to push the labels to either edge of the hbox;

edit:  oops yeah i meant 100%

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom label renderer along the lines of @greg's answer is probably the way to go.  One caution though when using custom item renderers where you add additional elements is to check the associated control class's `measure`method to make sure that the size of the additional elements will be taken into account when the control (the `List`in this case) is sized.  Otherwise you might end up with an unexpected result.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103945/flex-custom-item-renderer-for-combobox-controls-truncates-text/1688600#1688600) post for an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `itemRenderer` that looks like

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%">
    <mx:Label textAlign="left" left="0" text="{_text1}"/>
    <mx:Label textAlign="right" right="0" text="{_text2}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```